# Can't open minimized windows

Tags: plank, gala

When I minimize application and than I want to unminimize, I can't. I click on the app on plank, the app is activated but it's not showing.

Video expample: https://vid.me/GwnW

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Just curious: does it happen with the default theme too?

Comment: Does this happen just with Pantheon Files, or with other native apps like Scratch?

Comment: It happens with every theme I chose and with every app, not just Pantheon Files.

Comment: This error line is displayed when I click on some app in plank: https://vid.me/e/PnTB